# Why is this C code not counting the number of elements in the array for me?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, sizeof, function-definition

Unable to count number of elements in an array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int counter(int arr[])
{
    int c =0;
    for (int i = 0; arr[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        c = c + 1;
    }
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 5, 3 };
    int d = counter(a);
    printf("%d ", d);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone pls help me on how to obtain 3 as the output for this?

Comment: You seem to be confusing strings and arrays. You can't assume that an array is null-terminated. In fact, what would you want for the array `{1,2,3,0,4,5,6}`? By your logic, counting would stop at the middle element.

Comment: An int array is not necessarily null-terminated, pass the length of the array as well.

Comment: You seem to think that all arrays are automatically terminated by a null character.  They aren't.  Your `counter` function has no way of knowing when to stop looking.  Even if you did decide to reserve some integer value as a terminating value, and even if it happened to be zero, you'd simply use `0`, not `'\0'`, and you'd need to explicitly include it in your initializer list.  But it would be much more standard to simply pass the array length as an additional argument, eliminating the need to a special terminating value.

Comment: It should be noted that for static sized arrays, you could have the compiler pre-calculate the size at compile-time instead. `size_t size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);`. This will be replaced with the number 3 at compile-time, so it takes no execution time at all.

Comment: @Rogue, a `char` array is not necessarily null terminated, either.  Nor an array of any other element type.

Answer (score 6):

Your array needs to have a [sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) value at the end (I have chosen `0` but it can anything which will not be considered as valid data).

```
#define SENTINEL 0

int counter(int arr[])
{
    int c =0;
    for (int i = 0 ; arr[i] != SENTINEL; i++)
    {
        c = c + 1;
    }
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 5, 3, SENTINEL};
    int d = counter(a);
    printf("%d\n",d);


    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/TWGseeP8s

Comment: Using `i` and `c` seems redundant.

Comment: @chqrlie indeed, but it is not important in the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You declared an array of objects of the type `int` that is initialized the following way

```
int a[] ={1,5,3};
```

So the array has three elements and neither element of the array is equal to `0`.

So this loop within the function

```
for (int i=0 ; arr[i]!= '\0'; i++)
```

does not make sense and results in undefined behavior.

Pay attention to that the escape character constant `'\0'` has the type `int` and may be written simply as `0`.  The escape character constant `'\0'` is usually used with character arrays (see the demonstration program below).

Moreover this function declaration

```
int counter(int arr[]);
```

is adjusted by the compiler to the following declaration

```
int counter(int *arr);
```

That is the parameter having array type is adjusted to pointer to the element type.

To make your code working you need to set the last element of the array to `0` like for example

```
int a[] = { 1, 5, 3, 0 };
```

or you could explicitly specify the number of elements equal to `4` in the array declaration like

```
int a[4] = { 1, 5, 3 };
```

In this case the last element that has no explicit initializer will be implicitly zero initialized. That is the above two declarations of the array are equivalent.

But your function actually will not return the number of elements in the array.

It returns the number of elements in the array before the element with the value equal to `0` provided that such an element indeed exists in the array. However an array can be declared with more elements then the number of the element with the value `0`.

So in general your approach is wrong.

The for loop used in your function is usually used to determine the length of a string stored in a character array because strings are sequence of characters terminated by the zero character `'\0'`.

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t counter( const char s[] )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0 ; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        ++n;
    }

    return n;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "Hello World!";

    size_t n = counter( s );

    printf( "The length of the string is %zu\n", n );

    return 0;
}
```

But integer arrays can have an element with the value 0 as an actual element of the arrays.

So your approach will not work.

To determine the number of elements of the array you could just write

```
#include <stdio.h>

nt main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 1,5,3 };

    size-t n = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    printf( "%zu\n", n );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might also suggest using `s[i] != 0` instead of `s[i] != '\0'` as using `'\0'` for an `int` is confusing (albeit correct).

Answer (score 1):

You try and check for the `\0` value as the last value of the array although it was never declared.

The common way of finding the array length in C is to use the `ARRAY_LENGTH` macro:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAY_LENGTH(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 5, 3};
    printf("%zu\n",ARRAY_LENGTH(a));
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, this is all done in compilation since `sizeof` is known in compilation time, so it's even more efficient :)

After compiling the program, you will see something like this (pseudo of course):

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 5, 3};
    printf("%zu\n", 3);
    return 0;
}
```